# Log JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, applicationcontext

i use Spring to send email in my application.
   I want to log the imap server operation, when i send emails.
   I try to implement log in my applicationContext.xml  as follow:

```
<bean id="JavaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${smtpHost}" />
    <property name="port" value="${smtpPort}" />
    <property name="username" value="${userName}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="session" ref="mailSession" />
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    </props>
</bean>
```

but doesn't works.Any suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Eh, log IMAP operations when _sending_ email?

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the outer property.

```
...
<property name="session" ref="mailSession">
<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
...
```

Comment: Another question?is possible to redirect the debug in a log file?

Comment: Yeah. The JavaMail `Session` has a `setDebugOut(PrintStream)` method. Call `JavaMailSenderImpl.getSession()`, in a `@PostConstruct` to get your hands on it. Then call `setDebugOut()` with a `PrintStream` that writes to a file. I don't know how to easily integrate that into an existing logging system like log4j or logback, though.

Comment: Newer versions of JavaMail can log using java.util.logging.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answers, my version of JavaMailSenderImpl doesn't has setDebugOut() method, so i try to insert in my log4j properties log4j.category.com.sun.mail=FATAL but doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: `setDebugOut(PrintStream)` is on `Session`, not on `JavaMailSenderImpl`. As @BillShannon said though, JavaMail 1.4.3 and later can use java.util.logging (JUL), with a logger on `javax.mail`. To get that working with log4j, you'll need to bridge JUL to log4j. Best look into SLF4J if you want to do that.